Torah service on shabbat with no kohanim and not enough yisraelim
If there are no kohanim in shul on shabbat, Ashkenazi practice is to give the first aliyah to a levi or yisrael, and the subsequent six aliyot to yisraelim. (See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 135:6,9,10.)
What happens if there are no kohanim and five or fewer yisraelim, with the rest of the minyan made up of leviim? Presumably in these cases, one would give aliyot to more than one levi.
How should the seven aliyot be distributed between the leviim and yisraelim?
Ideally, answers should address the six cases ranging from zero yisraelim to five yisraelim, and specify which aliyot go to which type of person in each case.
(I’m asking mainly about these specific scenarios in order to keep the question more manageable. Feel free to expand your answer to include other scenarios with one or more kohanim, some leviim and insufficient yisraelim.)

We had a similar situation and the answer I got (and we actually practiced in our shul) was that once there's no Cohen, anything goes.

Why only ask about where there are no kohanim. Something like 4K 4L 2Y is equally confounding. (I happen to daven at a minyan like yours weekly)

@DoubleAA. Indeed. Just trying to keep the question more manageable. There are a lot of possible permutations. But more expansive answers are of course welcome.

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.135.12. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.135.44.

The regular rules for Aliyah positions are based on three rules: 1) kohen and levi read first if available to avoid fighting about who reads first (Gittin 59a), 2) a kohen should not read directly after a different kohen, nor levi after another levi, so as not to make people wonder if the first one was found to be invalid (Gittin 59b), 3) some say Rule 2 applies even if the two are not directly adjacent since the latter 5 aliyot are generally for Yisraelim some might come to question the validity of the latter kohen/levi (cf. Shulchan Aruch OC 135:10), and some say not to worry about this third rule if calling another Kohen-Levi-Yisrael triad (cf. Mishna Berura, ibid :37).
The Shulchan Aruch (OC 135:12) rules that if you're stuck then we allow breaking all those rules. Since Rule 3 is highly disputed, that'd be the first to go. Accordingly, it comes out that you basically do as close to a repeating Kohen-Levi-Yisrael as possible as many times as needed to fill out 7 people.
There are two caveats to keep in mind. First, if the case is one with at least one Yisrael and no Levi, then the first triplet would be Kohen-Kohen-Yisrael like an ordinary situation of no Levi, but not subsequent triplets since those are arguably not actually necessary as triplets. Second, if there are only Kohanim and exactly one other, or only Leviyim and exactly one Yisrael, the Shulchan Aruch (:12) rules we flip the script and put the singleton first to avoid fighting and continue with repeating statuses from there.
Example case of 2 Leviyim and 1 Yisrael: Kohen, Levi, Yisrael, Kohen, Levi, Kohen, Kohen.
Example case of 0 Leviyim and 3 Yisraelim: Kohen, same Kohen, Yisrael, Kohen, Yisrael, Kohen, Yisrael.
Example case of 0 Leviyim and 1 Yisrael: Yisrael, Kohen, Kohen, Kohen, Kohen, Kohen, Kohen.

More about the different positions in rishonim (such as giving up on leining 7 aliyot or giving aliyot to women/children or giving the same kohen all 7 aliyot) https://hakirah.org/Vol23Broyde.pdf

In your second example, AH OC 135:28 says that it would be better to do Kx2,Y,K,Y,Y,K. (He also quotes MA as saying do Kx2,Y,Y,Y,K,K, but doesn’t understand why that should be.)

@JoelK yes but iirc that's about a place that generally gives shvii to a kohein, which I personally have never seen. That said it's probably fine since the last K can also be seen as opening a new truncated set of three.

@JoelK I did omit that MA because it seems to be saying we'd rather give up rule 1 later than rule 3 earlier. There's a logic there about delaying breaking the law, but given the controversy around 3 it seems hard to buy here

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1597&st=&pgnum=379 Seems to have additional rules (no idea if these are commonly accepted) in cases where there are no kohanim. Prefers to give first two aliyot to yisraelim, and then alternate levi, yisrael

@JoelK Hmm Maharshag does sort of say that https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1278&st=&pgnum=108 but I don't understand what your source is referencing in the Beit Yosef. I hear that someone could think the chashash is stronger on the second aliyah I guess, but it doesn't seem to be a classical formal rule. Like YLYLYLL/YLYLLLL should still be better than YYLYLLL/YYLLLLL since you avoid an extra LL. Only if there are 4 Ys (YYLYLYL vs YLYLYLY) then it's the same either way (like what I said above about AhSh Kx2YKYYK).

But that's all in the opinion that 2-5 Ys has the same rule as the Yerushalmi about one. But the ShA seems to (cf MB 44) rule that that's only if there's exactly one Y, so once there are 2 Ys you can start LYLY. Unless you are always makpid not to give Levi rishon (not sure if that hakpada should even apply here when נתפרדה החבילה לגמרי)

I think his point is that the SA ruling that the Yerushalmi only applies to precisely one Y is where we have the competing priority of וקדשתו. Once we are not dealing with kohanim, then he claims everyone agrees to extend the Yerushalmi to a case of more than one Y.
